# How can I make my client and server IPv6 compatible? (Flutter, Python, Nginx)

Tags: python, nginx, networking, udp, ipv6

I have a mobile app that sends location information to database. The server (Tavu.io) is Ubuntu based and uses Nginx. The problem is that when I try to connect to the server using IPv6 address, the data is not transferred. The application should work in IPv6 network only. UDP protocol should be used.

In the nginx.conf, there are path to files included that contain:

```
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server;
```

netstat -pnltu shows that "tcp" and "tcp6" have LISTEN. But, there is only "udp", and no "udp6" which I assume it should be. There is no LISTEN on "udp".

My Python socket is like this:

```
        self.connection = db.connect_to_database()
        self.status = True
        self.udp = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)
        self.udp.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, 1)
        self.udp.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        self.udp.bind(('', 50943))
```

And the mobile client (Dart/Flutter):

```
 static String serverIP = '[ipv4 address hardcoded]';

  static Future<RawDatagramSocket> rDgS =
      RawDatagramSocket.bind(InternetAddress.anyIPv4, 50943);
```

```
 rDgS.then(
        (RawDatagramSocket udpSocket) {
          udpSocket.writeEventsEnabled = true;
          List<int> data = utf8.encode(message);
          udpSocket.send(data, InternetAddress(serverIP), 50943);
        },
      );
```

That above code works at that state as intended, but when is use hardcoded IPv6 address and change to .anyIPv6, the sent data is not reaching the server. No error is shown on the VSCode console though. The reason the IP addresses are hard coded because I don't have the hostname for the server and giving server name to nginx.conf was not working. Is there a workaround to this issue to have client to connect to server while in IPv6-only network?

I have changed the settings on nginx and attempted multiple times this application on IPv6-only network but the data (location and username) are not sent to database.

Comment: Using hardcoded addresses is a bad practice (we have had DNS for many years). If it is a link-local address, then you need to include the Zone ID.

Comment: How can I use DNS if I don't have a hostname? I only have the rDNS address.